# Elements created by script not recognized by another script

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

First of all I just want to say sorry if this is a duplicate - I found similar questions but no solutions that worked for my particular problem.

So, I recently completed a script which reads data from an xml file and adds it to an html page. The way the script works is that it looks for nodes with a certain tag name and for each one of those it adds a `<div>` to the html page's `<main>` using [jQuery's append() function](http://api.jquery.com/append/).

```
$("main").append("<div></div>");
```

I have another script that should find all `<div>`s in `<main>` and put them in an array:

```
$(window).load(function() {
   var divs = $("main > div").toArray();
}
```

My problem is that these newly created divs are not recognized by this function, and therefore the rest of my script doesn't work. My guess is that the last script runs too soon and therefore doesn't find any divs (the scripts MUST be run automatically - I don't have any buttons that can activate the function).

What would be the best way to fix this? Any help is very much appreciated!

EDIT: To make things clearer I will add all code I think is relevant (commented in Swedish, sorry!):
XML to HTML converter:

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
  var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
      if (xhttp.readyState == 4 && xhttp.status == 200) {
      myFunction(xhttp);
      }
  };
  xhttp.open("GET", "BlackBox/contents.xml", true);
  xhttp.send();

  function myFunction(xml) {
    var xmlDoc = xml.responseXML;
    var xmlNodes = xmlDoc.documentElement.getElementsByTagName("*"); // Guidens noder
    // Loopa igenom alla noder i XML-filen
    for(var i = 0; i < xmlNodes.length; i++) {
      // Lägg alla nuvarande divs under main i en array
      var divs = $("main > div").toArray();
      // Senast tillagda <div>
      var currentDiv = divs[divs.length-1];
      if(xmlNodes[i].tagName == "section") {
        // Noden är en <section> -> Vi ska göra en div i main
        $("main").append("<div></div>");
      } else if(xmlNodes[i].tagName == "name") {
        // Noden är en <name> -> Vi ska göra en ny länk i <nav> & ge senaste <div> ett id
        if(xmlNodes[i].parentNode.tagName == "section") {
          // Vi ska göra en vanlig länk och ge en div ett id
          $("nav > ol").append("<li><a href='#" + $(xmlNodes[i].firstChild.nodeValue) + "'>" + xmlNodes[i].firstChild.nodeValue + "</a></li>");
          $(currentDiv).id = xmlNodes[i].firstChild.nodeValue;
        } else {
          // Vi ska göra en länk i en redan skapad ul och ge en <li> ett id
          $("nav > ol > ul").last().append("<li><a href='#" + $(xmlNodes[i].firstChild.nodeValue) + "'>" + xmlNodes[i].firstChild.nodeValue + "</a></li>");
          $("main > div > ul > li").last().id = xmlNodes[i].firstChild.nodeValue;
        }
      } else if(xmlNodes[i].tagName == "header") {
        // Noden är en <header> -> Vi ska lägga till en header (h1 om det är den första, annars h2)
        if(xmlNodes[i].parentNode.tagName == "section") {
          // Nodens parent är en <section>
          if(divs.indexOf(currentDiv) == 0) {
            $(currentDiv).append("<h1>" + xmlNodes[i].firstChild.nodeValue + "</h1>");
          } else {
            $(currentDiv).append("<h2>" + xmlNodes[i].firstChild.nodeValue + "</h2>");
          }
        } else {
          // Nodens parent är en <sub> - innehållet ska hamna i den senast skapande <li>-taggen och vara h3.
          $("main > div > ul > li").last().append("<h3>" + xmlNodes[i].firstChild.nodeValue + "</h3>");
        }
      } else if(xmlNodes[i].tagName == "text") {
        // Noden är en <text> -> Vi ska lägga till text i <div>
        if(xmlNodes[i].parentNode.tagName == "section") {
          // Nodens parent är en <section>
          $(currentDiv).append("<p>" + xmlNodes[i].firstChild.nodeValue + "</p>");
        } else {
          // Nodens parent är en <sub> - innehållet ska hamna i den senast skapande <li>-taggen och vara h3.
          $("main > div > ul > li").last().append("<p>" + xmlNodes[i].firstChild.nodeValue + "</p>");
        }
      } else if(xmlNodes[i].tagName == "sub"){
        // Vi ska lägga till en <ul> i <nav> och currentDiv
        $("nav > ol").append("<ul></ul>");
        $(currentDiv).append("<ul><li></li></ul>");
      }
    }
  }
});
```

The function that should use the newly created divs:

```
// window load används för att funktionen ska köras när allt annat är klart
$.when(
  $.getScript("/js/xmltoguide.js"),
  $.Deferred(function(deferred) {
    $(deferred.resolve);
  })
).done(function() {
  // Spara alla divnamn som man ska kunna klicka sig till
  var divs = $("main > div").toArray();
    alert(divs[1]);
  // Lägg till klassen current på första länken (den är alltid den man startar på)
  $("a[href$='#" + divs[0].id + "']").addClass("current");
  $(window).scroll(function() {
    // Om divvens avstånd till toppen är tillräckligt litet får dess länk klassen current
    // Villkoret anger godkänns om skillnaden är -1. Det beror på länkarna som leder till divvarna i nav.
    for (var i = 0; i < divs.length; i++) {
      if ($(window).scrollTop() - $("#" + divs[i].id).offset().top > -1) {
        $(".current").removeClass("current");
        $("a[href$='#" + divs[i].id + "']").addClass("current");
      }
    }
    // Om man har skrollat längst ner ska sista länken automatiskt få klassen "selected"
    if ($(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height() == $(document).height()) {
      $(".current").removeClass("current");
      $("a[href$='#" + (divs[divs.length - 1].id) + "']").addClass("current");
    }

  });

  // Gör så att när man klickar på länkar som länkar till divvar animeras sidan
  $(document).on('click', 'a[href^="#"]', function(e) {

    // förhindra standardnavigation om man klickar på länk till div
    e.preventDefault();

    // målelements id
    var id = $(this).attr('href');

    // målelement
    var $id = $(id);
    if ($id.length === 0) { // === betyder att de måste ha samma värde och värdestyp
      return;
    }

    // topposition relativt till dokumentet
    var pos = $(id).offset().top;

    // animera scroll
    $('body, html').animate({
      scrollTop: pos
    });

  });

  $("#toggleHeader").funcToggle('click', function() {
    $("header").animate({
      left: "-=250px"
    });
    $(this).animate({
      left: "-=250px"
    });
    $("main, footer").animate({
      marginLeft: "-=250px"
    });
  }, function() {
    $("header").animate({
      left: "+=250px"
    });
    $(this).animate({
      left: "+=250px"
    });
    $("main, footer").animate({
      marginLeft: "+=250px"
    });
  });
  alert(divs[0]);
});
```

Comment: Make sure the scripts are running in the right order.

Comment: can you show them together in a file which run them?

Comment: @BlueEyedBehemoth If you're asking if they are included in the html document in the right order, then yes. Otherwise - that is exactly what my question is: How can I make them run in the right order?

Comment: @user1587426 Do they have to be called in different functions?

Comment: @BlueEyedBehemoth Yes. The scripts do entirely different things.

Comment: @user1587426 Could you post all of the code? You could just make sure that the function that executes on the load is called again after a div is added.

Comment: take `function myFunction(xml)` out of `$(document).ready()` and make `.done(function() {` it's own function. At the end of `myFunction`, call `.done(function() {`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to everyone for their answers! I couldn't really find what I was looking for, but I managed to solve the problem by using `getElementsByTagName("div")` instead of `$("main > div")`. In my case this worked but it may not in other cases. If anyone visits this question later I suggest trying the other peoples answers first, since my solution isn't really a good one.

Answer (score 0):

In your case you better use promises and **[deferred objects](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/JavaScript_code_modules/Promise.jsm/Deferred)** to make sure the first script is loaded, so you can call the second:

```
$.when(
    $.getScript( "/mypath/myscript1.js" ),
    $.Deferred(function( deferred ){
        $( deferred.resolve );
    })
).done(function(){

    //place your code here, the scripts are all loaded
    var divs = $("#main > div").toArray();

});
```

And also make sure to use the appropriate selector for `main`, I think it's an id so use `#main`instead.

Comment: It's not an id - it's a tag. It still does not seem to work - the array is still empty.

Comment: Have you tried to load the scripts on a differed mode?

Comment: What do you mean by that?

Comment: Have you used `$.when`, `$.getScript` and `$.Deferred` like I mentioned?

Comment: It means in your main page only include the second script, where you load the first script dynamically using `getScript`.

Comment: I think so - I added the script in my original question. Thanks your help!

Comment: Can you please show a screenshot of your directories hierarchy? Is this `"/js/xmltoguide.js"` a correct path?

Answer (score 0):

Just a quick check to be sure `$("main")` is an element or is main an ID en therefor `$("#main")` same for the append and the retrieval.

Also if both scripts are supposed to be run in order be sure to call them in order.

simple trick is to call the second function from the first

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("main").append("<div></div>");
  second();
});


function second(){
 // in a different file
  var divs = $("main > div").toArray();
  // do something with the divs or stuff.
}
```